# Failed to fetch connection timeout error inside docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I'm trying to build my laravel app via sail using this command:

```
vendor/bin/sail up --build --remove-orphans
```

This command is throwing a connection timeout error like this:

```
#0 197.5 E: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.2/php8.2-common_8.2.4-1%2bubuntu22.04.1%2bdeb.sury.org%2b1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to ppa.launchpadcontent.net:443 (185.125.190.52), connection timed out [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
#0 197.5 E: Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/pool/main/p/php8.2/php8.2-opcache_8.2.4-1%2bubuntu22.04.1%2bdeb.sury.org%2b1_amd64.deb  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpadcontent.net:https: [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

LABEL maintainer="Taylor Otwell"

ARG WWWGROUP
ARG NODE_VERSION=18
ARG POSTGRES_VERSION=15

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV TZ=UTC

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2 dnsutils \
    && curl -sS 'https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c' | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg > /dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y php8.2-cli php8.2-dev \
       php8.2-pgsql php8.2-sqlite3 php8.2-gd php8.2-imagick \
       php8.2-curl \
       php8.2-imap php8.2-mysql php8.2-mbstring \
       php8.2-xml php8.2-zip php8.2-bcmath php8.2-soap \
       php8.2-intl php8.2-readline \
       php8.2-ldap \
       php8.2-msgpack php8.2-igbinary php8.2-redis php8.2-swoole \
       php8.2-memcached php8.2-pcov php8.2-xdebug \
    && curl -sLS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer \
    && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_$NODE_VERSION.x | bash - \
    && apt-get install -y nodejs \
    && npm install -g npm \
    && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list \
    && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null \
    && echo "deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && apt-get install -y mysql-client \
    && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-$POSTGRES_VERSION \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/22.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/msprod.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y yarn \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 \
    && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y mssql-tools \
    && apt-get install -y unixodbc unixodbc-dev \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

RUN setcap "cap_net_bind_service=+ep" /usr/bin/php8.2

RUN groupadd --force -g $WWWGROUP sail
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash --no-user-group -g $WWWGROUP -u 1337 sail

RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
RUN source ~/.bashrc

RUN pecl install sqlsrv
RUN pecl install pdo_sqlsrv

RUN printf "; priority=20\nextension=sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/sqlsrv.ini
RUN printf "; priority=30\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so\n" > /etc/php/8.2/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
RUN phpenmod sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

COPY start-container /usr/local/bin/start-container
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY php.ini /etc/php/8.2/cli/conf.d/99-sail.ini
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/start-container

EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["start-container"]
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.2
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.2/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - mailpit
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
        ports:
            - 8080:80
        environment:
            MYSQL_USERNAME: "${DB_USERNAME}"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${DB_PASSWORD}"
            PMA_HOST: mysql
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 64M
        networks:
            - sail
    mailpit:
        image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
```

#### NOTE

The error occurs when I use my organization's wifi. It works fine when I use mobile data. My docker version is 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1, docker compose version v2.16.0

Comment: A colleague had the same problem, in reverse. Failed with mobile connection and worked with corporate VPN... Have you tried pinging the domain?

Comment: I can access the links in my browser. Connection timeout occurs only inside the container.

Comment: try to ping ppa.launchpadcontent.net from the container